# Anaconda Navigator create new enviorment and it doesn't show up

Tags: anaconda

I just downloaded Anaconda and I'm using Navigator for the first time on Windows.  I've been using Conda through the command line for awhile now, so I'm familiar with the concept of environments and how to use them.  Right now, the only enviorment showing up in navigator is root.  I want to install some additional packages, so I went ahead and cloned the root environment.  This doesn't cause any errors, and seems to have worked, except I don't see my new environment.

I know the enviorments are successfully being created, as I can see them when I go through the Anaconda Prompt.

Any thoughts why this is not working?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I've made multiple environments in the command prompt, but when I try to create a new environment in Anaconda navigator, it spins forever and nothing happens. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from this question : [Anaconda Navigator does not show new environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541283/anaconda-navigator-does-not-show-new-environments)

It goes like this:

1) Check that the new environment is there from conda prompt:

```
conda info --envs
```

[image]

2) update conda

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

[image]
[image]
3) restart your computer (I don't know if it will work by only restarting the conda navigator). Your new environment should be list in your anaconda navigator.

[image]