# Anaconda Navigator does not show new environments

Tags: anaconda

When I add a new environment in Anaconda Navigator it will create the environment, but it won't show it in the UI.

I can see the environment via the prompt, so I know it has been created. It just won't show it in the UI.

What do I need to do to get it to show up in the UI?

[image: UI just shows the root environment!]

Answer (score 8):

Please update Anaconda-Navigator by running

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

and restarting.